# How to start mongod but ignore invalid index in existing db file?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have some data files from a previous mongodb instance. I want to start a mongodb server and load those data files.

```
$ ll
total 4708880
drwxrwxr-x  3 rshi rshi      12288 Sep 11 08:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 51 rshi rshi       4096 Sep 11 07:51 ..
-rw-------  1 rshi rshi   67108864 Sep 11 07:44 okex.0
-rw-------  1 rshi rshi  134217728 Sep 11 07:44 okex.1
-rw-------  1 rshi rshi  268435456 Sep 11 07:44 okex.2
-rw-------  1 rshi rshi  536870912 Sep 11 07:44 okex.3
-rw-------  1 rshi rshi 1073741824 Sep 11 07:44 okex.4
-rw-------  1 rshi rshi 2146435072 Sep 11 07:44 okex.5
-rw-------  1 rshi rshi 2146435072 Sep 11 07:45 okex.6
-rw-------  1 rshi rshi   16777216 Sep 11 07:45 okex.ns
$
```

However, `mongod` complains about invalid index "$exist" (should be "$exists") and refuse to load the data. This prevents me from reading the data and potentially import them into a correctly indexed db.

```
$ mongod --dbpath .
2018-09-11T08:03:05.264-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=28583 port=27017 dbpath=. 64-bit host=rshi-7600
2018-09-11T08:03:05.264-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
2018-09-11T08:03:05.264-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
2018-09-11T08:03:05.264-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
2018-09-11T08:03:05.264-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-09-11T08:03:05.264-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-09-11T08:03:05.264-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-09-11T08:03:05.264-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-09-11T08:03:05.264-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-09-11T08:03:05.265-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "." } }
2018-09-11T08:03:05.265-0700 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - ./mongod.lock is not empty.
2018-09-11T08:03:05.265-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in . created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
2018-09-11T08:03:05.274-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=./journal
2018-09-11T08:03:05.274-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover begin
2018-09-11T08:03:05.274-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] info no lsn file in journal/ directory
2018-09-11T08:03:05.274-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover lsn: 0
2018-09-11T08:03:05.274-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover ./journal/j._0
2018-09-11T08:03:05.281-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover applying initial journal section with sequence number 31087
2018-09-11T08:03:05.283-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] recover create file ./local.ns 16MB
2018-09-11T08:03:05.421-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] recover create file ./local.0 64MB
2018-09-11T08:03:05.932-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover cleaning up
2018-09-11T08:03:05.932-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2018-09-11T08:03:05.932-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] old journal file will be removed: ./journal/j._0
2018-09-11T08:03:06.080-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover done
2018-09-11T08:03:06.080-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] preallocating a journal file ./journal/prealloc.0
2018-09-11T08:03:14.521-0700 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2018-09-11T08:03:14.521-0700 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-09-11T08:03:14.544-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-09-11T08:03:14.547-0700 F INDEX    [initandlisten] Found an invalid index { v: 1, key: { stimestamp: 1 }, name: "stimestamp", ns: "okex.ltc_btc_full", partialFilterExpression: { stimestamp: { $exist: true } } } on the okex.ltc_btc_full collection: BadValue: unknown operator: $exist
2018-09-11T08:03:14.547-0700 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28782 at src/mongo/db/catalog/index_catalog_impl.cpp 174
2018-09-11T08:03:14.548-0700 F -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure


$
```

**Question: is there any way I can load the data?**  It's okay to get rid of the index.

Possible solution might be the following but I have no idea how to do them (googled but no apparent result):

- Ignore the (broken) index by using some parameter in `mongod` command line.
- Use tools to modify the data file directly to remove the index before running `mongod`.
- Use tools to fix the index before running `mongod`.

Side note: I recall that I created this index via pymongo by running something like the following. I tend to think it's a bug of mongodb and pymongo that they accepted an invalid index during run time but then cannot cope with it at restart. But that's not the focus here. The focus is "how do we load my (broken) data".

```
coll_full.create_index([('sequence', pymongo.ASCENDING)], name='sequence', partialFilterExpression={'sequence': {'$exist': True}})
```

**EDIT:**

`--noIndexBuildRetry` doesn't work for me.

```
$ mongod --dbpath . --noIndexBuildRetry
2018-09-11T11:40:42.516-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=29657 port=27017 dbpath=. 64-bit host=rshi-7600
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: ".", indexBuildRetry: false } }
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - ./mongod.lock is not empty.
2018-09-11T11:40:42.517-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in . created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
2018-09-11T11:40:42.526-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=./journal
2018-09-11T11:40:42.526-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover begin
2018-09-11T11:40:42.526-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] info no lsn file in journal/ directory
2018-09-11T11:40:42.526-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover lsn: 0
2018-09-11T11:40:42.526-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover ./journal/j._0
2018-09-11T11:40:42.527-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover cleaning up
2018-09-11T11:40:42.527-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2018-09-11T11:40:42.527-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] old journal file will be removed: ./journal/j._0
2018-09-11T11:40:42.669-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover done
2018-09-11T11:40:42.669-0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] preallocating a journal file ./journal/prealloc.0
2018-09-11T11:40:51.108-0700 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2018-09-11T11:40:51.108-0700 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-09-11T11:40:51.133-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-09-11T11:40:51.136-0700 F INDEX    [initandlisten] Found an invalid index { v: 1, key: { stimestamp: 1 }, name: "stimestamp", ns: "okex.ltc_btc_full", partialFilterExpression: { stimestamp: { $exist: true } } } on the okex.ltc_btc_full collection: BadValue: unknown operator: $exist
2018-09-11T11:40:51.136-0700 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28782 at src/mongo/db/catalog/index_catalog_impl.cpp 174
2018-09-11T11:40:51.136-0700 F -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure


$
```

Comment: [--noIndexBuildRetry](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-noindexbuildretry) ?

Comment: Thank you for trying, Alex. However it didn't work directly. I added the console output to the question.

Comment: Try to repair it https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/

Comment: Hi @AlexBlex, the `--repair` command worked. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You could write a proper step-by-step answer. I just gave you a hint.